# Anyone else with problems installing Rugarch Package in R?

Tags: r, time-series

Folks, i tried to install rugarch package in my Mac (i have the latest version of R and everything updated)

i tried all the suggestions done on previous posts (but they are aged):
- install Xquartz (didnt help)
- install rgl (installs but doesnt show as available package)
- update packages and R version

after installing both packages shows still below

```
 library(rgl)
Error in library(rgl) : there is no package called 'rgl'
> library(rugarch)
Error in library(rugarch) : there is no package called 'rugarch'
>
```

I would like to install rugarch, because i have a model to run with exogenous variables.

Comment: Hello Paulo, it might seem like a small thing, but could you try `install.packages("rugarch")`, and check what the output states? There might be an error, giving an idea as to what is the cause. Including it in the post might help me and others to help you out.

Comment: @Oliver sure, i didnt before because it was quite big. There you go below (Still not full message):

Comment: ```During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw'
ERROR: dependency 'ks' is not available for package 'rugarch'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rugarch'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'rugarch' had non-zero exit status```

Comment: it says the same for: ```Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'ks' had non-zero exit status ```and  ```Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'mclust' had non-zero exit status```

Comment: I am not quite sure what is wrong, but searching for each of the components that the warning gives you, might give you a clue. Maybe updating R to 3.6 will fix the issue magically, you could try this.

Comment: @Oliver indeed it worked!! Amazing, i didnt notice that there was a 3.6 version. Updated and worked. Cheers

Comment: I am glad i could help. :-)